# Redirect all subsites to one site

Tags: apache

I have a website running on Apache. The address is http://helpdesk.example.com/otrs/customer.pl

I would like to create a forward such that if I access http://helpdesk.example.com/otrs/anyname (except customer.pl) this redirects to http://helpdesk.example.com/otrs/customer.pl

Also I'd like to not show the path of the website in the URL:

http://helpdesk.example.com/otrs/customer.pl displayed as http://helpdesk.example.com/

Thanks you for help!

Comment: This is not really a programming related question, it's more of a web server configuration issue. It might be better to ask this on ServerFault instead.